# Realice 2 ajax que me deberian hacer lo mismo pero solo uno me funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

```
$("#departamento").change(function (event) {
    $.get("municipios_dinamico/"+event.target.value+"",function (response,id_departamento) {

         console.log(response);
        // $("#unidades").empty();
        $("#municipio").empty();
        for (i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            $("#municipio").append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].nombre+"</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

este es mi otro ajax el problema que tengo que el primero me retorna un jason y quiero que este segundo me haga lo mismo pero me retorna un tipo html no me encuentra la ruta

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="departamento"]').on('change', function(){
        var id_departamento = $(this).val();
        if(id_departamento) {
            $.ajax({

                url: '/municipios_dinamico/'+id_departamento,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {

                    $('select[name="municipio"]').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(id, municipio){

                        $('select[name="municipio"]').append('<option value="'+ municipio.id +'">' + municipio.nombre + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('select[name="municipio"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

esta es mi ruta ala cual quiero entre el segundo igual

```
Route::get('municipios_dinamico/{id}',[
    'as'=>'municipios_dinamico',
    'uses'=>'icf@municipio_dinamico_get'
]);
```

esta es mi funcion del controlador

```
public static function municipio_dinamico_get(Request $request,$id)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            $municipios=municipios::municipios_dinamico($id);
            return response()->json($municipios);
        }
    }
```

y esta es mi funcion del modelo el cual la llamo en el controlador

```
public static  function municipios_dinamico($id){
        return municipios::where('id_departamento','=',$id)->get();
    }
```

Comment: Hola. Estos scripts estan dentro de un mismo documento en una misma url? ejemplo: los 2 estan en localhost/miweb/ o uno esta en localhost/miweb y otro en localhost/miweb/pagina ?

Comment: si ya lo resolvi solo tenia que quitar la pleca de la direccion

Comment: Pon un respuesta con la solución a tu problema, por si alguien se encuentra en la misma situación, mostrando el código cambiado. Así queda registro de la solución, vótala como pregunta aceptada. Un saludo.